# how to solve website speed test delay

Tags: web, pagespeed

So I have this wordpress blog set up on a VPS with litespeed and cloudflare. The website loads some banners from a revive insallation on the same VPS server, only that domain doesn't have cloudflare installed.

Although the page speed and wslow scores are good, I still get a 3 to 5 secs page load. You can see the results here:

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.survivalsullivan.com/WIZjVt68

Although individual resources seem to load fast (including the revive banners), there seem to be inexplicable "delays" in the waterfall... I'm no wiz in website optimization but do have some experience.

Am I missing something? I couldn't find a decent resource on how to read the waterfall, although I figured out most of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Overall you got pretty good results!

First of all deal with all those images gtmetrix displays: optimize them using photoshop, jpeg mini or sprites.

If you haven't already, install bj lazy load plugin and above the fold. 
Install and configure W3C cache which will fix the YSLOW settings that still not green in gtmetrix.

I assume you use some kind of theme / page builder? see if you can reduce the number of dom elements in page. Use DOM Monster! to see how nested is your page.
For example if need to display an image dont nest it in div inside column inside row inside container div.

If your website is gonna be used by users in multiple countries I would suggest paying for MAXCDN. It also integrated into W3C cache plugin.

If you use google fonts try adding them locally to style instead of GETing them.